# Lambda Input file into array

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I am at the last part of my assignment and am running into a snag. I need to convert the below code to a Lambda statement using the stream method of the InputData class, along with a forEach loop that has the same effect as the current loop. For the stream method, I was thinking of using...  inputData.stream().forEach(values ->  ....just inside the try block, but I cannot figure out the rest of the syntax for the forEach loop. Can someone point me in the correct direction? Thanks!

```
private List<AreaData> readInput(String filename) throws IllegalStateException,
        NumberFormatException
{
    /* This statement uses the "diamond" operator, since it is possible for
       the compiler to work out the required generic type. */
    final List<AreaData> result = new LinkedList<>();
    try( InputData inputData =
            new InputData(filename, InputData.class, null,
                    Field.values().length, ",") )
    {
        /* Iterate through each of the lines of values. */
        for( String[] values : inputData )
        {
            /* Create a new AreaData object, and add it to the list. */
            AreaData next = new AreaData(values);

            result.add(next);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `inputData.stream()` returns a `Stream<String[]>` you could use the map operation on the Stream to achieve this, instead of the `forEach` approach. The mapper function would take a `String[]` as parameter and would return a new `AreaData` instance (and you can use the constructor reference to shorten it). This is how the code would looks like using the map operation:

```
private List<AreaData> readInput(String filename)  throws IllegalStateException, NumberFormatException {
    try(InputData inputData = new InputData(filename, 
                                            InputData.class, 
                                            null, 
                                            Field.values().length, ",")) {
        return inputData.stream().map(AreaData::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

---

If you must use the `forEach` approach, what you basically have to do is that; for each `String` array in the `inputData` instance create a new `AreaData` instance and add it to the list (so the lambda would be `values -> result.add ...`). However I feel that this approach is a bit weird. In my opinion, the map operation is what you should do here because it's really a mapping to each array from a new `AreaData` instance.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, the assignment calls for the forEach loop to be used.

Comment: @TheDude76 I've edited my answer; if something is still unclear, let me know.

Comment: ZouZou  Thanks again for your reply. I see how using the map operation would be much simpler. This forEach loop really doesn't make as much sense in this situation. However, the forEach is what is called for :)    for this, would I use the Collector operation after the result.add?

Comment: @TheDude76 No, the `forEach` does just a traversal of the elements. It's a terminal operation which returns void (note that map returns a `Stream<U>` (assuming map is a function T => U)). Basically you should let the declaration of the list before the try-with-resources, and then in the `forEach` add the elements in the list.

Comment: @TheDude76 As the doc of `forEach `states: _"Performs an action for each element of this stream."_ so your action is adding a new `AreaData` instance to the list for each `String` array you encounter during the `Stream` traversal. Hope it's more clear now :-)

Comment: @TheDude76: you are telling contradicting things. Either your assignment is to use a stream or it is to use a loop. Using a loop and a stream at the same time makes no sense.